# Want a string variable in the title to be interpreted as LaTeX, in Julia/PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, tex

I am assigning text to a variable "title1" for display via the "title" command in Julia/PyPlot:

```
xintx = input();

Hstyle=string("M1-",xintx);

title1=string( L"Unfiltered \> Heater \> Currents \> , \> for \> the \> ", Hstyle,L" \> Process ");

title(title1,color=tiColor,fontsize=tifoSize,fontstyle=tifoStyle,fontweight=tifoWeight,fontname=tifoName)
```

By including the "L" in front of the quotation marks, I ensure that the quoted text will be interpreted as LaTeX. However, no matter what I try, I can't figure out how to have the text variable "Hstyle" also interpreted as LaTeX. I've tried searching for answers on the internet, but haven't found any. I've made a lot of guesses at what the correct syntax might be (eg. " L {[Hstyle]}"), but all I get are error messages.

I'm hoping that somebody out there knows how to do this.

Comment: What about  `Hstyle=L"M1-{0}".format(xintx)`?

Comment: Hi, I tried this in console and get:  julia>  Hstyle=L"M1-{0}".format(xintx)
ERROR: type LaTeXString has no field format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the LaTeXStrings package, you can convert a normal ASCIIString into a LaTeXString directly

```
julia> latexstring("helle")
L"helle"
```

Comment: btw, instead of trying to concatenate LaTeXStrings, instead I think it would probably be easier / less error prone if you constructed the entire normal string first, and then pass it as a single argument to LaTeXString(). Don't forget to escape dollar signs if you want to enter mathmode. e.g.   `LaTeXString( string( "This is a graph of the \$int_a^b x dx \$ integral" ))`

Comment: Hi Tasos, Thanks for your help. I did previously try LaTeXString. What I find is that even though I define it as a LaTeXString, it is not interpreted as LaTeX by the "title" command. It is processed as though it was a regular string. This is a really strange behavior, that I don't understand.

Comment: I just tried an experiment, with very strange results: I define a variable of type string, prefacing the quotation marks with an "L" for LaTeX. When I use the string in the title, it is interpreted as LaTeX, whereas the LaTeXString was not interpreted as LaTeX. What I did was: julia> zz=string(L"helle");
zz
L"$helle$"    -notice the $ signs, which were not there in the LaTeXString result. But unfortunately, I still can't render an existing variable as LaTeX in the title.

Comment: @JuliaNewbie Just play around a bit. For instance, `LaTeXString("The integral from a to b is \$ \\int_a^b x dx \$")` is equivalent to `L"The integral from a to b is $ \int_a^b x dx $"`. Try this in your title.

Comment: what's the exact latex string / variable symbol you're trying to display?

Comment: Hi Tasos, That's the problem - the exact string is not known until runtime. In this case I use keyboard input, but often the text will come from a csv file.

Comment: @JuliaNewbie, I stand corrected. Please read the documentation of the LaTeXStrings module. (i.e. type `?LaTeXStrings` on your terminal). `LaTeXString()` is a low-level constructor. What you want is the `latexstring()` function; This seems to do *almost* exactly what you want (i.e. interpolate strings, and convert them to L-strings directly). It also talks about your problem. The short answer is basically **No**: your `HStyle` variable *needs* to be properly escaped, e.g. `\$ \\int_a^b \$`. There does not seem to be a way to convert a "normal", unescaped latex instruction directly to a (cont..)

Comment: LaTeXString format, without misinterpreting the sequences. You *could* attempt to "escape things manually" as preprocessing (i.e. replace in your strings all $ with \$ and all \ with \\ etc) ... but that might not work if you come across an unpredicted sequence that had to be escape also.

Comment: Also, if the expectation is that you'll push a generic "latex expression that would otherwise compile ok in latex" into matplotlib to be used as a title, then you should know that its latex parser is fairly limited. You're probably better off generating an 'image' of the title and placing it over your plot to serve as a title. Bit roundabout and hacky, I know, (and involves being able to run a latex command on your system) but this is a lot more guaranteed to work if there are *no* restrictions in your latex input (i.e. it's completely unpredictable)

Comment: Hi Tasos, 
I should've mentioned that the input() test contains only numbers, and no math formulas. Sorry for the confusion. 
I have found two ways to make this work, and one of them uses your latexstring() function. The answer will not fit in here as a "comment", so I will put it below. Thank you very much for your suggestions, which have ultimately led to the solution.

Comment: With the help of Tasos I have found two solutions. The first is:  
xintx=("M1-", input());
Hstyle=latexstring(xintx);
title1=string( L"Unfiltered \> Heater \> Currents \> , \> for \> the \> ", Hstyle,L" \> Process ");
title(title1,color=tiColor,....)

and the other one is: 

Hstyle=string("\$ M1-",input(),"\$");
title1=string( L"Unfiltered \> Heater \> Currents \> , \> for \> the \> ", Hstyle,L" \> Process ");
title(title1,color=tiColor,....)

These two methods render equivalent titles.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about these is that there is quite a big space between the "M" and the "-", and again between the "-" and the text variable. I tried using \!, but that didn't work. This is a TeX thing, and I'll just have to work it out. 
Thanks so much to Tasos, and also for the suggestion from Serenity.